# How to disable communication between DCs in a multi-DC environment?

Tags: cassandra

In a multi-DC implementation in a cluster, say DC1=rack1, DC2=rack2, if I am doing any maintenance on one of the DCs, how I disconnect the DC under maintenance from the cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently possible to disable communication between datacenters. The typical method to do this right now is to disable communication (thrift/native) on all hosts in a datacenter, using '[nodetool disablethrift](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsDisableThrift.html)' or '[nodetool disablebinary](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsDisableBinary.html)'